# Can I insert CSS class name into wix button or element?

Tags: css, velo

I am new in using Wix, I need to insert my own CSS class name so I can manage my Google Tag manager trigger better, it will less error prone. I need to insert css class name like this

```
<div class="widget-container my-own-css-class-name-here">
```

I need to insert CSS class like that using Wix, how to do that? can I insert something like that using Wix Website Editor?